# How can I narrow the type of a readonly property of a derived class?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to extend `Uint8Array` such with a class that constrains the type to a certain length.  For example:

```js
class Bytes32 extends ByteArray {
    constructor() { super(32) }
    length: 32 = 32
}
```

However, when I try to instantiate that class I get an error because the `length` property on `Uint8Array` only has a getter:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property length of [object Object] which has only a getter
```

If I don't do the assignment in the class declaration and instead only do `length: 32` then I get a compiler error saying that `length` is never assigned.

Is there any way I can tell TypeScript (either via assertion of via proof) that the `length` property of this class will *always* be `32` and thus its type should be narrowed to `32` from `number`?

I specifically want the compiler to know about the narrowing so I can have a function with a signature like:

```js
function apple(data: ArrayLike<number> & { length: 32 })
```

Such a signature would enhance type checking in my project, without tightly coupling to any specific array of numbers container.  The only requirement is that the thing they give me must (provably by the compiler) have exactly 32 elements.

Comment: FYI, constraining `length` does not affect its usage in spread syntax. For rest parameters, TypeScript will still infer just 0 or more arguments, not 32 arguments, for example.

Comment: Note that `TypeError: Cannot set property length of [object Object] which has only a getter`  is a runtime error. To understand why, consider that adding elements to an array mutates its length property. You'd be better off with a wrapper for a number of reasons.  and you can write such a rapper without duplicating all definitions

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yeah, it is unfortunate that TS doesn't provide a narrowed type definition for spread arrays, but that is something that I can accept for my needs.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes, I understand _why_ I get the error.  I'm trying to figure out a way that I can tell the type checker, "I'm certain that this class's length is always `32` even though the base class has a length of `number`.  The initial `length: 32 = 32` was just what I tried at first but the error makes total sense.  I don't actually _need_ the assignment, I just want the type assertion to be applied to the derived class's `length` property but I can't do that either.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, now I understand. Given that, you can write `class Bytes32 extends ByteArray{} interface Bytes32 {readonly length: 32;}` which leverages decoration merging

Comment: @AluanHaddad That appears to work.  If you create an answer with that I can mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you simply wish to refine the type of the `length` member, specifically from `number` to `32`, and are only initializing it to satisfy type checking and thereby introducing a runtime error, we can resolve the issue by leveraging [Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html).

Specifically we can refine the typeof of `length` to `32` by introducing an interface which declares the property and merges with the class itself.

The following does the trick

```
interface Bytes32 {
  readonly length: 32;
}

class Bytes32 extends Uint8Array {
  constructor() { super(32); }
}
```

This technique has a broad range of applications but also needs to be used with care.

Comment: Is there a trick to apply the same technique to a mixin class? Declaring an interface with the same name as the class returned in a mixin function seems to have no effect at all.